# Homotopy pullbacks and pushouts of spectra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Is it true that homotopy pullbacks and homotopy pushouts coincide in the category of spectra? I had a feeling that this is the case, but don't know where to find a proof or how to prove it.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes. This is a consequence of the Blakers-Massey theorem.

Comment: if you accept the fact that the category of spectra is stable, then it follows from the axioms of being stable (how tautological was this comment?)

Comment: Dylan, in some sense it's more elementary than Blakers-Massey. To get the idea, here's why $X\to \Omega\Sigma X$ is a weak equivalence when $X$ is a spectrum: $X$ consists of spaces $X_n$; the map is given by Freudenthal maps $X_n\to \Omega\Sigma X_n$; an inverse on spectrum homotopy groups is given by the obvious maps $\Omega\Sigma X_n\to \Omega X_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 3):

Although the answer is sketched in the comments, I wanted to remark that this statement is proved carefully by Cary Malkiewich as Proposition 6.2.11 in [Parameterized Spectra, A Low Tech Approach](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.04773.pdf). He credits [Model Categories of Diagram Spectra](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/%7Ebshipley/MMSS.pdf) as the first place this was proven, but I couldn't find the result there.

Comment: First of all, that proof is unreadable :), second of all, he only reduces from the case of parametrized spectra to usual spectra and cites a different paper for that.

Comment: Still, good to have references for the result that one can cite.